# What is the use of style="clear:both"?

Tags: html, css

I happened to see a `div` which had the style `clear:both`!  What is the use of `clear` in `style`?

```
<div style="clear:both">
```

Answer (score 253, accepted):

`clear:both` makes the element drop below any floated elements that precede it in the document.

You can also use `clear:left` or `clear:right` to make it drop below only those elements that have been floated left or right.

```
+------------+ +--------------------+
|            | |                    |
| float:left | |   without clear    |
|            | |                    |
|            | +--------------------+
|            | +--------------------+
|            | |                    |
|            | |  with clear:right  |
|            | |  (no effect here,  |
|            | |   as there is no   |
|            | |   float:right      |
|            | |   element)         |
|            | |                    |
|            | +--------------------+
|            |
+------------+
+---------------------+
|                     |
|   with clear:left   |
|    or clear:both    |
|                     |
+---------------------+
```

Comment: Also it makes parent div to fit the height.

Comment: @Jason, the bug you referring to is only applicable for Internet Explorer 6 on Windows XP. It is a good thing we don't need to support it most of the times these days.

Comment: @YevgeniyAfanasyev, yes, this is true. My comment is from 2009 when that was still applicable.

Answer (score 20):

Just to add to RichieHindle's answer, check out [Floatutorial](http://css.maxdesign.com.au/floatutorial/), which walks you through how CSS floating and clearing works.

Comment: On 15 Feb 2016, I was unable to connect to the server for Floatutorial (connection refused on port 80).

Answer (score 3):

When you use float without width, there remains some space in that row. To block this space you can use `clear:both;` in next element.