# How use clear:both?

Tags: html, css

```
<div class="one">aaaaaaaaaa </div>
<div class="one">bbbbbbbbbb </div>
<div class="one">ccccccccccc </div>
<span style="clear: both">
    THIS SHOULD BE BELOW TABLE. WHY NOT?

.one {
  background-color: red;
  float: left;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bLsju/2/

Why in this example still is float? How can i use clear:both?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the use of style="clear:both"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1012131/what-is-the-use-of-style-clearboth)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

can you please check this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/bLsju/7/), it may be help you. use DIV instead of span.

Answer (score 8):

The `clear` property is ignored if the element is no block element. Use  `style="display: block"` on the span or use a div, which is a block element.

Comment: `display: block` on a span? Why not use a `div` then?

Comment: @GolezTrol: you're right. Using div would be better in this example. I updated my answer. I firstly wanted to tell OP why the clear attribute is ignored.

Answer (score 5):

Change the `span` to a `div`. It will work on block elements.

Answer (score 4):

Clear only works on elements with display type block. Add `display: block;` to make it work as intended.

Answer (score 3):

Use div instead of span, because span is inline element. You can write clear for block elements.

http://jsfiddle.net/bLsju/2/

Answer (score 1):

```
 <div style="clear: both">&nbsp;</div>
```

instead of span because its inline element

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the span is not a block element.
either make it block. by using "display:block" as style attribute

or you can use div instead of span

see these 2 links:

jsfiddle.net/bLsju/7/

jsfiddle.net/wmT9w/

you'll understand easily.

Answer (score 0):

Use a div. If you insist on a span do:

```
<span style="display:block;clear: both"></span>
```

Answer (score -1):

clear:both makes the element drop below any floated elements that precede it in the document.

duplicate of : [What is the use of style="clear:both"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1012131/what-is-the-use-of-style-clearboth)