# Double last-child calls, one works, the other doesn't

Tags: css

I have my code here: http://jsfiddle.net/u9BsD/2/

You will see the second section #indoorRange the last-child is being applied pushing the last box to the right and extending the width 1% more.  The first section #membership is the exact same, but with three blocks but the last-child class is not effecting the element it should.  Is there some rule surrounding the last-child rule I am not aware of?

Thank you for your help.

```
<div id="memberships">
<div class="greyHeading">
    <header>
         <h3>Individual Membership:</h3>

    </header>
    <p>$175.00</p>
</div>
<div class="greyHeading">
    <header>
         <h3>Family Membership:</h3>

    </header>
    <p>$200.00 (Includes spouse and children under 21)</p>
</div>
<div class="greyHeading">
    <header>
         <h3>Red, White and Blue Discounts:</h3>

    </header>
    <p>Active LE, military, and 1st responders: 1/2 price membership discount!</p>
    <p>Retired LE, military and 1st responders 25% discount on membership!</p>
</div>
<div class="cl"></div>
</div>
<div id="indoorRange">
<div class="greyHeading">
    <header>
         <h3>Range Fees</h3>

    </header>
    <p>The range fees are per session. A "session" is defined as a visit to Allen
        Arms Indoor Shooting Range. We reserve the right to limit sessions to one
        hour if other customers are waiting for lanes.</p>
    <p>All lanes limited to two shooters unless special permission is obtained
        in advance.</p>
</div>
<div class="greyHeading">
    <header>
         <h3>Single Session</h3>

    </header>
    <ul>
        <li>One Adult Shooter: $10.00</li>
        <li>Two Adult Shooters on Same Lane: $7.50 Each</li>
        <li>Children under 18 with paying adult guardian: Free</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="greyHeading">
    <header>
         <h3>Ladies Day</h3>

    </header>
    <p>Every Wednesday is Ladies Day! Women shoot for $5.00. Additionally, women
        receive 20% off range memberships.</p>
</div>
<div class="greyHeading">
    <header>
         <h3>Red White and Blue Discounts</h3>

    </header>
    <p>Law Enforcement, Active Duty Military, First Responders, and Security
        personnel pay only $5.00 per session any time, and receive 50% discount
        on memberships!</p>
</div>
</div>


#memberships .greyHeading {
float: left;
width: 32%;
margin: 0 1% 0 0;
}
#memberships .greyHeading:last-child {
float: right;
margin: 0;
width: 33%;
}
#memberships .greyHeading header {
background: #666;
margin: 0 0 10px 0;
}
#memberships .greyHeading header h3 {
color: #fff;
text-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
line-height: 25px;
margin: 0;
padding: 5px 0 1px 5px;
}
#indoorRange .greyHeading {
float: left;
width: 24%;
margin: 0 1% 0 0;
}
#indoorRange .greyHeading:last-child {
float: right;
margin: 0;
width: 25%;
}
#indoorRange .greyHeading header {
background: #666;
margin: 0 0 10px 0;
height: 55px;
}
#indoorRange .greyHeading header h3 {
color: #fff;
text-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
line-height: 25px;
margin: 0;
padding: 5px 0 1px 5px;
}
```

Comment: There is no hidden rule that you are missing...  What's odd is that you can remove the entire rule for :last-child for the indoorRange ID, and not even that makes the first one work.  Working on it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `<div class="cl"></div>` from the HTML and add `#indoorRange { clear: both; }` to the css, I believe this fixes it.

The styling wasn't applied to the last memberships greyHeading as due to the `<div class="cl">` element it wasn't actually the last child.

EDIT: [fiddle for proof](http://jsfiddle.net/N8weQ/)

EDIT2: I was right about the cl div having the style applied, you may be able to use the `last-of-type` pseudo selector to achieve what you want also, I don't know what browser support is like unfortunately.

See this SO question for more information:

[CSS last-child selector: select last-element of specific class, not last child inside of parent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7298057/css-last-child-selector-select-last-element-of-specific-class-not-last-child-i)

Comment: Normally when you use floats elements inside parent  you need `clear:both` the parent  to fit the height from him.  `clear:both` makes the element drop below any floated elements that precede it in the document [SEE HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1012131/what-is-the-use-of-style-clearboth)

Answer (score 0):

This is not the most ideal answer as it does not solve why :last-child is not working.  However, this does work for me, and may be a suitable solution.

All I did was switch from using last-child to nth-child.  So these two particular classes are the changes...  I also added background colors to make it more visually obvious that they are working in the jsfiddle that is here: http://jsfiddle.net/u9BsD/3/

```
#memberships .greyHeading:nth-child(3) {
    float: right;
    margin: 0;
    width: 33%;
    background: red;
}

#indoorRange .greyHeading:nth-child(4) {
    float: right;
    margin: 0;
    width: 25%;
    background: blue;
}
```