# html: div messed up

Tags: css, html, firebug

The html file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Patients Detailed Information Page</title>
<link  href="test.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
<div id="detailed_fistpart">
    <div id="detailed_div_image">
    </div>
    <div id="detailed_div_basicinfo">
        <div class="detailed_div_inner">
            <div class="detailed_div_captain"><strong>Basic Info</strong></div>
            <div>
                <table id="detailed_table_basicinfo">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="detailed_table_td"><font color="#9c9a9c">Name</font></td>
                        <td class="detailed_table_td"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="detailed_table_td"><font color="#9c9a9c">Gender</font></td>
                        <td class="detailed_table_td"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><font color="#9c9a9c">Birthday</font></td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="detailed_div_contactinfo">
        <div class="detailed_div_inner">
            <div class="detailed_div_captain"><strong>Contact Info</strong></div>
            <div>
                <table id="detailed_table_contactinfo">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="detailed_table_td"><font color="#9c9a9c">Phone</font></td>
                        <td class="detailed_table_td"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="detailed_table_td"><font color="#9c9a9c">Email</font></td>
                        <td class="detailed_table_td"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><font color="#9c9a9c">Address</font></td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="detailed_div_reminding">
    <textarea id="detailed_reminding"></textarea>
    <input type="button" class="button" value="update"></input>
</div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

and this is my css file:

```
body{
margin:0;
padding:0;
}

#container{
width:900px;
margin:0 auto;
text-align:left;
position:relative;
filter:alpha(opacity=100);
opacity: 1.0;
}

#detailed_fistpart {
margin-top: 10px;
}

#detailed_image {
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
}

#detailed_div_basicinfo {
margin-left: 10px;
float: left;
background-color: #FFF;
border: 1px solid #c6cfde;
border-radius:7px;
}

.detailed_div_inner {
margin-top: 20px;
margin-left: 20px;
margin-right: 20px;
margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.detailed_div_captain {
font-size: 20px;
height: 40px;
}

#detailed_table_basicinfo {
width: 193px;
height: 118px;
font-family:"Times New Roman", Times, serif;
font-size:14px;
}

.detailed_table_td {
border-bottom: 1px solid #efefef;
}

#detailed_div_contactinfo {
margin-left: 10px;
float: left;
background-color: #FFF;
border: 1px solid #c6cfde;
border-radius:7px;
}

#detailed_table_contactinfo {
width: 400px;
height: 118px;
font-family:"Times New Roman", Times, serif;
font-size:14px;
}

#detailed_div_reminding {
width: 900px;
}

#detailed_reminding {
width: 700px;
height: 70px;
}

.button {
background-color: #004584;
font-size:16px;
color: #FFF;
font-weight: bold;
}
```

And when I use `firebug` (the extension), I can see that it is the div with id=detailed_div_reminding includes the div with id=detailed_div_basicinfo and div with id=detailed_div_contactinfo rather than the div with id=detailed_fistpart.

One problem is that if you add `magin-top: 20px` to `#detailed_div_reminding`, it doesn't produces margin with `#detailed_fistpart`

Why?

Comment: what is the question? whats wrong with it?

Comment: @1337holiday you can see the problem using firebug. And one problem with this is if you add `margin-top: 20px` to the div#detailed_div_reminding. it is not as expected

Comment: Why do you have an XML declaration?

Comment: @Blender it is not working either after I deleted that

Comment: so you basically want 3 columns? basic_info, contact_info and a form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hi there u need to add this line
 `<div style="clear:both"></div>`

before this line of code `<div id="detailed_div_reminding">`

Comment: this is amazing. can you tell me what happened here?

Comment: i think you need to give a look at this http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_clear.asp  and you can also take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1012131/what-is-the-use-of-style-clearboth

Comment: Do not post w3schools link here in SO and get a downvote.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Did you  mean that you are not getting the margin on top of your last section? It is because you have floats present and and you need to clear them for subsequent section.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Patients Detailed Information Page</title>
<link  href="test.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<style>
body{
margin:0;
padding:0;
}

#container{
width:900px;
margin:0 auto;
text-align:left;
position:relative;
filter:alpha(opacity=100);
opacity: 1.0;
}

#detailed_fistpart {
margin-top: 10px;
}

#detailed_image {
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
}

#detailed_div_basicinfo {
margin-left: 10px;
float: left;
background-color: #FFF;
border: 1px solid #c6cfde;
border-radius:7px;
}

.detailed_div_inner {
margin-top: 20px;
margin-left: 20px;
margin-right: 20px;
margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.detailed_div_captain {
font-size: 20px;
height: 40px;
}

#detailed_table_basicinfo {
width: 193px;
height: 118px;
font-family:"Times New Roman", Times, serif;
font-size:14px;
}

.detailed_table_td {
border-bottom: 1px solid #efefef;
}

#detailed_div_contactinfo {
margin-left: 10px;
float: left;
background-color: #FFF;
border: 1px solid #c6cfde;
border-radius:7px;
}

#detailed_table_contactinfo {
width: 400px;
height: 118px;
font-family:"Times New Roman", Times, serif;
font-size:14px;
}

#detailed_div_reminding {
width: 900px;
margin-top:20px;
}

#detailed_reminding {
width: 700px;
height: 70px;
}

.button {
background-color: #004584;
font-size:16px;
color: #FFF;
font-weight: bold;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
<div id="detailed_fistpart">
    <div id="detailed_div_image">
    </div>
    <div id="detailed_div_basicinfo">
        <div class="detailed_div_inner">
            <div class="detailed_div_captain"><strong>Basic Info</strong></div>
            <div>
                <table id="detailed_table_basicinfo">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="detailed_table_td"><font color="#9c9a9c">Name</font></td>
                        <td class="detailed_table_td"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="detailed_table_td"><font color="#9c9a9c">Gender</font></td>
                        <td class="detailed_table_td"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><font color="#9c9a9c">Birthday</font></td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="detailed_div_contactinfo">
        <div class="detailed_div_inner">
            <div class="detailed_div_captain"><strong>Contact Info</strong></div>
            <div>
                <table id="detailed_table_contactinfo">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="detailed_table_td"><font color="#9c9a9c">Phone</font></td>
                        <td class="detailed_table_td"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="detailed_table_td"><font color="#9c9a9c">Email</font></td>
                        <td class="detailed_table_td"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><font color="#9c9a9c">Address</font></td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div style="clear:both" ></div>

<div id="detailed_div_reminding">
    <textarea id="detailed_reminding"></textarea>
    <input type="button" class="button" value="update"></input>
</div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```