# What is wrong here? Twitter timeline in bottom corner?

Tags: html, css, twitter

I'm currently building a website but the twitter timeline (widget) it sat in the bottom right hand corner.

(Just a heads up, This is my first website and not the best at coding).

I just want it to sit next to the little youtube widget. Or isn't there a way of doing this?

[Source of problem](http://baileyiglesias.host56.com/home)

(If the website above is not working just wait a couple of minutes and retry)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove the `<div style="clear: both"></div>` after `<div id="youtube">...`

Also, in css:

```
#twitter{
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 50px; /*or whatever padding you want to give */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you want it next to the video (as I can't see a YouTube widget there) then you have a `<div>` with a style of `clear: both` inbetween both divs, this will prevent anything being placed to the left or right of that div which is why it is appearing lower down.

See [What is the use of style="clear:both"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1012131/what-is-the-use-of-style-clearboth) for an example of what I mean.