# Jquery toggle content position

Tags: jquery, css

**The page html**

```
<div class="outbox">
<p class="heading">Header-1 </p>
<div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
<p class="heading">Header-2</p>
<div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
<p class="heading">Header-3</p>
<div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.outbox
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.heading
{
    background-color: #FF6666;
    border: 1px solid #FF5050;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 1px;
    padding: 3px 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    float: right;
    width: 300px;
    height:25px; 
}



.content
{
  background-color: #FFCCCC;
}
```

JQUery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".content").hide(); 
  $(".heading").click(function()
  {
    $(this).next(".content").slideToggle(500);
  });
});
</script>
```

When I click any heading of the content, the expanded part always appears on the top of the page. How can I display it below the heading? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

**HTML**

```
<div class="outbox">
    <div class="container">
        <p class="heading">Header-1 </p>
        <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <p class="heading">Header-2</p>
        <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <p class="heading">Header-3</p>
        <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.outbox
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.heading
{
    background-color: #FF6666;
    border: 1px solid #FF5050;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 1px;
    padding: 3px 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 300px;
    height:25px; 
}
.container{
    float:right;
}


.content
{
  background-color: #FFCCCC;
}
```

**Fiddle**  http://jsfiddle.net/LMWpZ/

Comment: thank you, it works. the only issue when there are multiple rows the content mis-aligns. I fixed setting width of the content section as follows.  .content
{
  background-color: #FFCCCC;width:300px;
}

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `float: right;` style from your heading. Unless it's there on purpose, but in that case your question would sound strange.

Answer (score 1):

Your header elements are floated, but their adjacent divs aren't.

Just remove or adjust the `float: right;` property of your `heading` class.

Here's a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/GpJKe/

Answer (score 0):

Float right your `.content` class and add `clear:both` to your `.heading` and `.content` and try the below approach:

```
.heading {
    clear: both;
    background-color: #FF6666;
    border: 1px solid #FF5050;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 1px;
    padding: 3px 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    float: right;
    width: 300px;
    height:25px;
}
.content {
    clear: both;
    float: right;
    background-color: #FFCCCC;
}
```

[What is the use of style=“clear:both”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1012131/what-is-the-use-of-style-clearboth)

Check out the [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/QdHxn/)