# CSS 3 Div Floats with Liquid center div

Tags: css

It's quite a simple question but I can't figure out what's wrong.

I have three divs, 2 of set pixel sizes and the other (the middle) fills the remaining space between the two.

```
|------|--------------------------|------|
|      |                          |      |
|      |                          |      |
|      |                          |      |
|------|--------------------------|------|
       <-------------------------->
                 Width Fill
```

I have the following CSS:

Left Div

```
#leftdiv {
    height: 50px
    width: 50px;
    float: left;
    }
```

Middle Div

```
#middlediv {
    min-width: 270px;
    width: calc(100% - 100px);
    width: -moz-calc(100% - 100px);
    width: -webkit-calc(100% - 100px);
    width: -o-calc(100% - 100px);
    float: left;
}
```

Right Div

```
#rightdiv {
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    float: right;
}
```

I've simplified it here, but basically the right div doesn't actually float, it goes underneath like so:

```
|------|--------------------------|
|      |                          |
|      |                          |     
|      |                          |      
|------|--------------------------|
                                |------|
                                |      |
                                |      |
                                |      |
                                |------|
```

Comment: This normally happens if the width on the parent div (the one containing the right columns) is not wide enough

Comment: Try putting the right `div` first in the HTML. If you would like a more detailed answer, please make a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Answer (score 0):

`clear:both` makes the element drop below any floated elements that precede it in the document.

so try using `clear: both` in `#rightdiv`.

For more information, check this [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1012141/1671639).

Answer (score 0):

```
#middlediv {
    min-width: 270px;
    width: calc(100% - 150px);
    width: -moz-calc(100% - 150px);
    width: -webkit-calc(100% - 150px);
    width: -o-calc(100% - 150px);
    float: left;
}
```

The sum of the widths of your div is exceeding the width of the screen, so the right div is pushed down

Answer (score 0):

Your  #rightDiv has a width of 100px when it needs to have a width of 50px

```
#rightdiv {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    float: right;
}
```

Otherwise the combined width of the left and right divs is 150px and you are only subtracting 100px

```
width: calc(100% - 100px); //100px is too small
```