# how to show one element under the other one?

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with my CSS in my html file.

I have two div's:

```
<div class="one">
    ....
</div>
<br>
<div class="two">
    ....
</div>
```

with the following css:

```
.one 
{
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}
.two 
{
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}
```

the problem: the first div is very big and the second should be under the first but it is not, its right from the first one.

how to fix this, so that the second div is under the first one starting at the left site of the page?

Comment: can you create a fiddle that shows the problem?

Comment: used to this .two{clear:left;}

Comment: How 'bout remove `float: left` in `.one` and `.two`?

Comment: "its right from the first one" : That's what `float: left` does.

Comment: the first float: left must be there because otherwise my html code inside does not look like it should.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A nice explanation for [Why clear?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1012141/1671639)

Add `clear: left` for `.two`

```
.two {
clear: left
}
```

Check this [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/6Dnkn/)

Answer (score 1):

```
.two{ position:relative; clear: left;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
float: left;
```

To

```
display: block;
```

Info on floats:

http://alistapart.com/article/css-floats-101

Info on `display` property in CSS:

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp

Answer (score 1):

Do `clear:both` on the second div. This will clear both the sides of the box and so no floating elements will be allowed on either sides.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to **clear** the first div.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make a menu for example, the best practice is to wrap your divs in a parent div:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="one">
        ....
    </div>
    <!-- remove the br -->
    <div class="two">
        ....
    </div>
</div>
```

with the following css:

```
.parent
{
    float: left;
}
.one 
{
...
}
.two 
{
...
}
```