# Issues with spacing while using a masterpage

Tags: html, css, vb.net, visual-studio

I am working with visual studio 2010 and I'm using a site.master page.  This is working out fine, but the issue I'm having now is that when I place the content that goes within the containers and I try to add space between the site master page and the page I'm working on nothing happens.  I want there to be a little space between each and nothing is working.  I've added margins to the bottom of the content page, breaks, and even line spacings and nothing is working.  If I have the following tags, nothing happens.

```
 <asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent"> 


    <div class="content">
     <br />
     </div>
     <br />


    </asp:Content>
```

The final div may not have any content in it, but it'll have margin information.  Even if I put the margin information in the last div that has content nothing is happening.  I just don't understand why it's not reading the spacing that I'm trying to enter in.

Comment: Without seeing that in context, have you tried a `<div style="clear:both;"></div>` after your possibly empty `<div>`? Or using an `&nbsp;` for blank content?

Comment: Putting the div with the style clear worked!!  Thanks for the help!

Comment: You're welcome :) I have made that comment into an answer; feel free to mark it as the answer if you feel it is appropriate.

Comment: Made this the answer!  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put a `<div style="clear:both;"></div>` after your possibly empty `<div>`.

There is a good explanation of how it works at [What is the use of style=“clear:both”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1012131/what-is-the-use-of-style-clearboth).