# what is the use of this div tag with only clear rule

Tags: html, css

I was noticing that `<div style="clear:both;"></div>` had been frequently used in a website between div areas. Given the fact that no other rules such as width and height has been specified for this, what is the effect of this type of usage? an example of the site code follows below

```
<div id="content">
<div id="middle-cont"></div>
<div id="bot-r">
  <div style="clear:both;"></div>
  <div class="hwd-module latest-audio"></div>
  <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
</div>

<style>
  #middle-cont {
    padding: 18px 0px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-right: -40px;
    margin-left: -40px;
}
#bot-r, #bot-c, #bot-l {
    width: 32%;
    height: auto;
    float: right;
    padding: 5px;
}    
</style>
```

Comment: Well, it clears the floats, as usual. Read the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clear).

Comment: But it does have no dimensions. According to [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_clear.asp), no floating elements are allowed on its right or left side. But, does this element exist on page to have the effect (it has no width or height)?

Comment: It doensn't have a width or height, the only function is to clear a floating elements that are above it to avoid divs positions being messed up

Comment: answer to [what is the use of style="clear:both"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1012131/what-is-the-use-of-style-clearboth) says clear:both makes the element drop below any floated elements that precede it in the document. My question is what is the use of dropping a nonexistent element below previous one?

Comment: I don't get you "to clear a floating element"

Comment: A div that has `float:left;` or `float:right;` on its CSS to be aligned at the left or right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Clear:both
```

is used to clear any (or for that matter, all preceding) floats.

It basically means "No floating elements allowed on either the left or the right side".

Let us try to understand this with a demonstration :

You can see a couple of examples below:

**No clear** -> http://jsfiddle.net/0xthns3k/

The html and css are as follows :

**HTML :**

```
<div class="left">
</div>
<div class="right">    
</div>
<!-- No clear -->
<div class="Green"></div>
```

CSS :

```
div {
    display:inline-block;
    width: 150px;
    height:150px;
}

.left {
    background-color:Orange;
    float:left;
}

.right {
    background-color:Red;
    float:right;
}

.Green {
    background-color:Green;
}

.yellow {
    background-color:yellow;
    width:30px;
}
```

This is the image of the generated HTML.

[image: No clear]

If you see here, the green colored box is placed somewhat in the center of the two floated elements. Well, actually since there are floated elements the new "non-floated" element is actually placed adjacent to the leftmost floated element. Hence, you see the green colored element just adjacent to the leftmost floated element.

Now, if you were to have another element(s) floated left, this would automatically fit between the Orange and the Green elements.

See this below :

[image: another left floated element]

http://jsfiddle.net/0xthns3k/1/

Also, the position of this 'new' left floated element wouldn't be that important too with respect to the said HTML.

*Placed below green element*

```
<div class="left">
</div>
<div class="right">    
</div>
<!-- No clear -->
<div class="Green"></div>
<div class="left yellow">
</div>
```

*Placed after right floated element.*

```
<div class="left">
</div>
<div class="right">    
</div>
<div class="left yellow">
</div>
<!-- No clear -->
<div class="Green"></div>
```

*Placed after left floated element*

```
<div class="left">
</div>
<div class="left yellow">
</div>
<div class="right">    
</div>
<!-- No clear -->
<div class="Green"></div>
```

All the above HTML code would generated the same HTML as shown in the image above.

**With clear** -> http://jsfiddle.net/bk3p160d/

The HTML is only slightly modified here :

HTML

```
<div class="left">
</div>
<div class="right">    
</div>
<div class="clearAll"></div>
<div class="Green"></div>
```

and one additional CSS class :

CSS

```
.clearAll {
    clear:both;
}
```

[image: Clear]

If you see here, the green colored element is positioned below the line containing the aforementioned floats. This is because "clear: both" tells the HTML rendering engine 
 "No floating elements allowed on either the left or the right side". Hence, it cannot place this element on the same line as it would violate the defination. This causes the engine to place it on a new line. On the line the preceding float properties are essentially nullified. **Hence, `clear:both` is used to effectively clear any preceding floats.**

See here for further information : http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_clear.asp

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: Will your third div have the same effect if it had no height and width?

Comment: @misaq It would have the same effect as long as it is occupying any space on the rendered HTML.