# CSS division inside the float center division

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create 3 column home layout, in which center, left and right looks fine, but I am unable to create 2 slider division inside div class `middle`, I actually expect slider1 should come on top, but should be inside the class `middle`, and slider2 after slider1 inside class `middle`.

As you can see here [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/dhvw7adz/) , slider2 and slider1 is not coming inside div class middle

This is my effort

**HTML**

```
<div id="content-container">
    <div class="middle">
          <div class="slider1"></div>
          <div class="slider2"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="left">
          <div></div>
          <div></div>
   </div>
   <div class="right">
          <div></div>
          <div></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
/* Container */
#content-container{
    background:white;
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    height:600px;
}

/* follow container height*/
.left,.right,.middle{
    height:100%;
}

.left{
    float: left; 
    width: 23%; 
    border:1px solid red;
}
.right{
    float: right; 
    width: 23%; 
    border:1px solid red;
}
.middle{ 
     display: inline-block; 
     width: 53%; 
     border:1px solid red;
}


/* Sliders */
.slider1 { 
        height: 50px;
        border:1px solid green; 
}
.slider2 {  

        height:60px; 
        border:1px solid green;
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Left right and middle should all have float left, not inline-block and float right, and do you want the sliders to be next to each other or on top of each other?

Comment: I can't find a div with class 'center'

Comment: You had several "typos": slider1 and MIDDLE not center. http://jsfiddle.net/fe8rbkwv/

Comment: that is also a very good point :P

Comment: Sorry guys my bad still its not working, can someone explain, I really didn't understand `clear:both` in many places people usually use.

Comment: you also still have a class that is called center in your css. please fix all names before you ask your question.

Comment: What is not working with my solution? clear:both http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1012131/what-is-the-use-of-style-clearboth

Comment: @DOCASAREL : Sir, right side division is coming down :(

Comment: Make the result window broader %)P You have fixed width!!

Answer (score 0):

something like this? added float: left; to slider1 also you miss spelled slider1 in css

```
.slider1 { 
        height: 50px;
        border:1px solid blue;
        overflow: hidden;
        float: left;
        background: blue;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fa308n2b/

Answer (score 0):

check your class name

```
.slder1 { 
        height: 50px;
        border:1px solid green; 
}
```

`.slder1`  It should be `.slider1`